# Mysql LEFT JOIN remover

Tags: mysql

I have an comment field where users can post questions and answers to each other.

The $row looks like this:

```
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.post_by = users.user_id WHERE posts.post_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

This is what it gets after they talk to eachother in the field:

User 1 writes "What can I Help you With?".
User 2 answers "Nothing Special".
User 3 says: "Okay, welcome back.".

User 1 reply again to the answer User 2 just gave, but this Second comment User 1 did is going straight to the top again, skipping User 2's answer and puts the comment over it. Like this:

User 1: What can I help you with?
User 1: Okay, welcome back.
User 2: Nothing special.

I want it to go like this:
User 1: What can I help you with?
User 2: Nothing special.
User 1: Okay, welcome back.

I don't know how to remove the LEFT JOIN users ON ( I guess that's the script that does this )

I want it to be: ORDER BY post_date DESC, comment after comment, not moving the Username's ID to stick with it.

How can i Change the following code to make it proper?

```
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.post_by = users.user_id WHERE posts.post_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

I Hope I was Specific enough, please let me know if there's anything else you need to know about the table or code.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_*() functions anymore, and your code is still insecure. what's to stop someone from doing `example.com/foo.php?id=posts.posts_topic` and getting ALL posts in your db? It might be escaped, but you're still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: are you storing a timestamp? maybe you can order them by the time.

Comment: So if I add an Timestamp to the Table, how do I insert it into the Row?

Comment: Have you tried an ORDER BY clause?  You don't have one in the code you posted.  Why do you think the Left Join has anything to do with the order of your results?

Comment: When you wrote "User 3", did you mean "User 1"? BTW, I think your question title is unrelated to what you actually ask and need.

Answer (score 0):

The left join links the friendly name of the user with the message so the display can be

```
User 1: What can I help you with?
```

Without the join all you could display is the user'd ID

```
1143245: What can I help you with?`
```

Obviously less than ideal.  There is no reason you couldn't just append the order by after the where clause

```
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users\
                ON posts.post_by = users.user_id\
                WHERE posts.post_topic = ". 
                mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']).
                " ORDER BY post_date";
```

Disclaimer:  The usual caveats about protecting against SQL injection, URL manipulation,  upgrading to mysqli apply.  But if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, I won't stop you.